# SUMIF - compare two columns of strings, sum related values

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a workbook with multiple sheets, where I am tracking people and their account balances. Each person has a unique alphanumeric ID in one column and the balance in a second column. I would like to be able to compare the columns of ID numbers between two sheets, and sum the corresponding balances from the previous sheet in a cell on the current sheet, so that I can track outstanding balances.

The attached image is a simple mockup of what I'm working with. The "test" sheet is last year's numbers, and the "result" sheet (see [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1192096/sumif-compare-two-columns-of-strings-sum-related-values#comment1731154_1192096)) is my current sheet, where I was trying to use SUMIF to compare the IDs in column A on "Test" to IDs in column A on "Result" to decide which IDs were missing from "Result" and sum the corresponding values in column B on "Test".

I am looking for a sum of the column of "balance" values, excluding those values associated with IDs that have been used on the current sheet. In the attached example, two IDs have been boxed in red. From 'September 2016' to 'October 2016' I did new business with those IDs, so their balance from September can be assumed paid. However, the other three IDs still owe, so I would like cell B8 on 'October 2016' to 1) check if an ID number listed in 'September 2016' is also listed on 'October 2016' and 2) if it is not, sum the corresponding 'Balances' and show that total. (1350 in the example I have posted) I hope this makes things more clear.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

The data in tabular form:

September 2016 worksheet:

```
ID      Balance
TV14    300
TY44    275
TU25    6690
TU30    650
TN41    775
```

October 2016 worksheet:

```
ID      Balance 
TT61        
TA82        
TU30        
TG30        
TU25        

September Balance       1350
```

Comment: Hi B. You forgot to change the image. They are both the same. And I don't see an Alphanumeric ID. Please use column headers so we can gather some intelligent idea of what your numbers represent.

Comment: This I think is what you are trying to do. I've posted the solution below. Since you are new, you might not know. Please Mark, or Click, the faint Check-Mark next to the Zero on the solution to accept the answer to let the community know it's been solved. Welcome to SuperUser!

Comment: ejbytes - thank you for the feedback on how to better my posts here. VLOOKUP was not a function in my repertoire, and that does seem to be the function I will need to complete this task, but your solution isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I have edited my original post with additional details and a better photo.

Comment: So the balance should be 7340?

Comment: I think you need to add a current table in your write-up. A table of current tables, and a table of desired table; exactly what your desired table should reveal with balances you desire as the result.

Comment: Reason $7340 makes sense is because there was an existing balance in Sept. and also Oct. Why no balances in Oct? September Balance, October Balance, November Balance, all have the same names. If it's a balance sheet then the prior balances should be forwarded. Unless this is only fictional data and the outcome is of other personal desire for some other project. The Reason is unclear why October has no balances at all and are blank. A desired result is one thing, but logic also plays into reasoning such results.

Comment: Okay, I understand your dilemma, although the presented data sheets are puzzling. But without going into that, the solution and explanation of the solution in detail is below; the solution formula and derivation of the solution in steps. Please check the check mark to complete the solution process.

Comment: Did this work out for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***EDIT: Following OP's Lead***

> I am looking for a sum of the column of "balance" values, excluding
>   those values associated with IDs that have been used on the current
>   sheet. In the attached example, two IDs have been boxed in red. From
>   'September 2016' to 'October 2016' I did new business with those IDs,
>   so their balance from September can be assumed paid. However, the
>   other three IDs still owe, so I would like cell B8 on 'October 2016'
>   to 1) check if an ID number listed in 'September 2016' is also listed
>   on 'October 2016' and 2) if it is not, sum the corresponding
>   'Balances' and show that total. (1350 in the example I have posted) I
>   hope this makes things more clear.

The above comment + OP's New Screen Shot gives way to this:

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
=SUM('September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6)-SUM(SUMIF('September 2016'!$A$2:$A$6,A2:A6,'September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6))
```

1. Cut/Paste, correct/modify tables (eg $A$1:$A$7) to point to
2. DO NOT simply press enter when complete, but instead `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to "tell Excel", "I'm summing an ARRAY of data." Excel will enter the braces (eg { } see last image) automatically.
3. **DONE**.

---

### EXPLANATION WHY IT WORKS

---

## *Proceed further if you need help in understanding the procedure and the thought process in the final solution.*

What the formula is?
**A**:

```
SUM('September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6)
```

Sum the values C2 through C6 contiguously (eg a single column table); on Sheet: September 2016

**B**:

```
SUMIF('September 2016'!$A$2:$A$6,A2:A6,'September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6)
```

If the values on 'this' page A2 through A6 (ID's) appear on Sheet September X, then sum the values in table C2 through C6 on September X. SUMIF(**range** to verify, **criteria**, **range to sum**).

1. **Range**: 'September 2016'!$A$2:$A$6
2. **Criteria**: A2:A6 ---- this local page that this formula is on
3. **Range Sum**: 'September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6

**C**:

```
SUM(SUMIF('September 2016'!$A$2:$A$6,A2:A6,'September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6))
```

Sum what is explained in explanation B above.

**D**:

```
SUM('September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6)-SUM(SUMIF('September 2016'!$A$2:$A$6,A2:A6,'September 2016'!$C$2:$C$6))
```

By entering this formula, it will Sum part C by stepping through the ARRAY (A2:A6) and SUM the values of the results as a Vector sum; this is why you must press `CNTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` or the intended formula will yield unwanted results as indicated by the OP in this solution.

See images:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Final Image With Solution.
[image]
**Click on any image to enlarge.**

Although several formulae are revealed in the images, this is only the process of thought revealed to a final conclusion. The final image reveals a single formula to yield the desired result.

Comment: Thank you ejbytes for this! That was exactly the solution. I'm sorry I couldn't be more forthcoming with details about what I'm trying to do, I am working with some private data. I very much appreciate you sticking with me through all my confusing explanations and terrible screenshots!

Comment: @B.Tracey You got it, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

`=SUMIF (Account! A2, VLOOKUP (Test! A2, Test! A1:B5, 2,FALSE), Account! B2:B5)`